# Overwriting a filter in plugin using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter, overwrite

I have the following filter in a WordPress plugin named 'JobBoard Package'

```
        function apply_job_validate($validate){
        $package  = jb_package_get_current_package();

        if(!$package){
            jb_notice_add(esc_html__('You need to purchase a package before applying job.', 'jobboard-package'), 'error');
            return true;
        }

        $applied  = JB()->candidate->count_applied_all();
        $limit    = get_post_meta($package->ID, '_apply', true);
        if($applied >= $limit){
            jb_notice_add(esc_html__('Apply job limited, you can update your package.', 'jobboard-package'), 'error');
            return true;
        }
        return $validate;
    }
```

Being called at the top of the plugin as follows:

```
    private function actions(){
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'add_scripts'));
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array ($this, 'get_menu_notice') , 100);
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'add_admin_scripts'));
        add_action( 'save_post_jobboard-post-jobs', array($this, 'save_post'));

        add_filter( 'jobboard_query_endpoint_args', array($this, 'add_endpoint'));
        add_filter( 'jobboard_query_endpoint_package_title', array($this, 'add_endpoint_package_title'));
        add_filter( 'jobboard_query_endpoint_transactions_title', array($this, 'add_endpoint_transactions_title'));
        add_filter( 'jobboard_employer_navigation_args', array($this, 'add_endpoint_menu'));
        add_filter( 'jobboard_candidate_navigation_args', array($this, 'add_endpoint_menu'));

        add_action( 'jobboard_endpoint_employer_new', array($this, 'get_template_add_new'), 0);
        add_action( 'jobboard_endpoint_employer_package', array($this, 'get_template_package') );
        add_action( 'jobboard_endpoint_candidate_package', array($this, 'get_template_package') );

        add_filter( 'jobboard_form_handler_validate_add_job', array($this, 'add_new_job_validate'));
        add_filter( 'jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array($this, 'apply_job_validate'));
    }
```

I have tried disabling apply_job_validate via the functions.php and as a plugin using the following code and its variations with no luck and would really appreciate some help.

```
if( class_exists('JB_Package' ) ){
  //This should work in whatever case
  remove_filter('jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array( 'JB_Package', 'apply_job_validate'));
  //or Instantiating a new instance
  //remove_filter('jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array( new JB_Package(), 'apply_job_validate'));
  //or Targeting the specific instance, not tested
  //remove_filter('jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array( JB_Package::get_instance(), 'apply_job_validate'));
}
```

I have also tried it as follows:

```
function remove_package() {
  if (class_exists('JB_Package')) {
    remove_filter('jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array( 'JB_Package', 'apply_job_validate'));
  }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','remove_package');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a later action hook, like `after_setup_theme`. You're hooking into `plugins_loaded`, which is fired before your functions.php file is parsed. Try:

```
function remove_package() {
  if (class_exists('JB_Package')) {
    remove_filter('jobboard_form_handler_validate_apply_job', array( 'JB_Package', 'apply_job_validate'));
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_package');
```

However, you should check to see when the 'JB_Package' class is hooked (if it's hooked at all). If it's hooked at `init`, then you need to hook into something later like `wp_loaded`.

```
//if class 'JB_Package' is hooked at 'init'
add_action('wp_loaded','remove_package');
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you have any advice on how to check if the class is hooked? I am still new with hooks but understand it is the better way of doing things.

Comment: I have tried removing more as follows but it does not seem to work for the rest https://anotepad.com/notes/csi3as

Comment: You can just look at the plugin file where 'JB_Package' is declared and see if they either hook it or initialize the class in some way.